# how can I get the phone number SID when I buy a twilio number using the REST API?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, twilio

I am using ruby, sinatra and twilio. The following code buys a number and then inserts the number into my database. I would like also to get the returned 34 character phone number "sid" and insert that into my database but I do not know how to access it.

Here is the code:

```
get '/buy_phone_number'do
#get subbacount credentials from my db
user_key = users.where(:validation => cookie).join(:credentials, :user_id => :id).get(:user_key)
user_token = users.where(:validation => cookie).join(:credentials, :user_id => :id).get(:user_token)
user_id = users.where(:validation => cookie).get(:id)
primary_number = users.where(:validation => cookie).get(:primary_number)
#search for the right number
@sub_account_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(user_key, user_token)
@subaccount = @sub_account_client.account
@numbers = @subaccount.available_phone_numbers.get('GB').toll_free.list({})
#buy the number and set the voice/sms url aprameters
@subaccount.incoming_phone_numbers.create(:phone_number => @numbers[0].phone_number, :voice_url => 'http://6c93ce61.ngrok.com/hello', :voice_method => 'GET', :sms_url => 'http://6c93ce61.ngrok.com/receive_sms', :sms_method => 'GET')
phone_number = @numbers[0].phone_number
#[HERE IS THE PROBLEM]sid = @numbers[0].Sid
numbers.insert(:user_id => user_id, :number => phone_number, :sid => sid, :inbound_route => primary_number, :send_to_voicemail => 'false', :show_caller_id => 'false')
return "You just bought: " + phone_number
```

This all works fine but the 34 character telephone number sid is not returned either by `@numbers[0].Sid` nor @numbers[0].phone_number_sid nor `@numbers[0].number_sid`

So there are 2 questions:

1) How can, in particular, access the number Sid?
2) How can I general see all the objects returned after the number is purchased?

Thank you as always for your help ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a Twilio developer evangelist, hope I can help.

The issue here is that the [AvailablePhoneNumbers resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers) doesn't respond with SIDs for the phone numbers it returns. You only get the SID when you purchase the number.

What you want to do is capture the response from purchasing the number using the [IncomingNumbers resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers). So, from the last part of your example, you would do this:

```
@numbers = @subaccount.available_phone_numbers.get('GB').toll_free.list({})
#buy the number and set the voice/sms url aprameters
@purchased_number = @subaccount.incoming_phone_numbers.create(:phone_number => @numbers[0].phone_number, :voice_url => 'http://6c93ce61.ngrok.com/hello', :voice_method => 'GET', :sms_url => 'http://6c93ce61.ngrok.com/receive_sms', :sms_method => 'GET')
phone_number = @purchased_number.phone_number
sid = @purchased_number.sid
numbers.insert(:user_id => user_id, :number => phone_number, :sid => sid, :inbound_route => primary_number, :send_to_voicemail => 'false', :show_caller_id => 'false')
return "You just bought: " + phone_number
```

As you can see, I assign the response to purchasing the number to `@purchased_number` and you can read the sid and the phone_number from there.

Let me know if this helps out.

Comment: Cheers Phil. Thank God for you. It is very confusing because the "resource properties" are listed, on the relevant api page, as Sid for example but the returned object is sid (with a small "s"). or even more confusingly "FriendlyName" becomes "friendly_name"; so what's a poor chap to do. This accounts for the second part of my question: how can I, in general, see all the objects returned? Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you're right the Ruby library doesn't follow the core documentation as such. That is so that it behaves a little more like a Ruby developer expects, as we tend to use lower cased, underscored method names. So, you can infer that if the documentation says 'FriendlyName' there will be a 'friendly_name' property. In order to see the properties of a Twilio object, you could try logging the results of `object.inspect` though I'm not sure if that will show everything. You can trust the docs and that conversion method though.

Comment: @philnash "evangelist" I don't know that scripts has religions now, how did the times changed

Comment: @PauAI it may be a weird job title, but it means I'm here to help. That's why I'm on SO, that's why I write blog posts about Twilio and why I'm always available to receive feedback about it. There's nothing religious here though, I can promise you that.